# An elementary property of tensor products.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm studying representations theory to start my Masters thesis. I'm using the book of ***J. P. Serre, Linear Representations of Finite Groups*** and in the pg. 55 He affirm:

> If $V$ is induced by $W$ and if $E$ is a $C[G]$-module, we have a canonical isomorphism 
>   $$Hom^H(W,E)\simeq Hom^G(V,E)$$ 
>   where $Hom^H(V,E)$ denotes the vector space of $C[G]$-homomorphisms of $V$ into $E$, and  $Hom^G(W,E)$ is defined similarly. This follows from an elementary property of tensor products.

Here, $G$ is a finite group, $V$ is a $C[G]$-module and $W$ a sub-$C[H]$-module of $V$.

**I'm trying to prove this but without success. Can someone explain how to proceed here? What is this property and how to use it?**

[EDIT]

In the book, He said to see also the following lemma:

> Lemma: Suppose that $(V,\rho)$ is induced by $(W,\theta)$. Let $\rho':G\rightarrow GL(V')$ be a linear representation of $G$, and let $f:W\rightarrow V'$ be a linear maps such that $f(\theta_tw)=\rho'_tf(w)$ for all $t\in H$ and $w\in W$. Then there exists a unique linear map $F:V\rightarrow V'$ which extends $f$ and satisfies $F\circ \rho_s=\rho_s'\circ F$ for all $s\in G$

Comment: Do you mean that $W$ is a $C[H]$-submodule of $V$? Also, isn't $Hom^H(V,E)$ the space of $C[H]$-homomorphisms from $V$ to $E$?

Comment: You are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of the property called [adjunction between the $Hom$ and the tensor functors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction).

Specifically, if $A$ and $B$ are two algebras over a commutative ring $k$, if $X$ is an $A$-$B$-bimodule, if $M$ is a right $A$-module and $N$ is a right $B$-module, then there is an isomorphism
$$ Hom_A(M, Hom_B(X, N)) \cong Hom_B(M\otimes_A X, N). $$

The property you wish to prove is then obtained by taking $A = C[H]$, $B=C[G]$, $M=W$, $N=E$ and $X=C[G]$.  Then we have $W\otimes C[H] = V$ and $Hom_{C[G]}(C[G], E) = E$, and thus obtain the desired isomorphism.

Now you can prove the adunction property directly, by defining the map
$$ Hom_B(M\otimes_A X, N) \to Hom_A(M, Hom_B(X, N)): f\mapsto (m\mapsto(x\mapsto f(m\otimes x))) $$
and showing that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Just for search-able keywords, adjunctions of this sort are often called "Cartan-Eilenberg" adjunctions/relations... although more and more I would think that many people intuited such relations earlier, without having the vocabulary (about Homs and such, proto-categorical or genuinely categorical) to say what they meant.

Comment: First of all, thank you.

In the book, He said to see also the following lemma:

>Lemma: Suppose that $(V,\rho)$ is induced by $(W,\theta)$. Let $\rho':G\rightarrow GL(V')$ be a linear representation of $G$, and let $f:W\rightarrow V'$ be a linear maps such that $f(\theta_tw)=\rho'_tf(w)$ for all $t\in H$ and $w\in W$. Then there exists a unique linear map $F:V\rightarrow V'$ which extends $f$ and satisfies $F\circ \rho_s=\rho_s'\circ F$ for all $s\in G$

Following this, we obtain the same proof that you proposed?

Comment: @Felipe Your are welcome! I think the lemma you mention should lead to a similar proof, yes.